# What's the difference between "validate" and "validates"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I added a validation to an objects using:

```
validate :field, presence: true
```

I found they do not give error messages. I changed them to `validates` and got the error messages. [This ticket](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4438-30-validates-vs-validate) is relevant.

I tried to add a custom validation with `validates` and got an error:

```
You need to supply at least one validation
```

I changed it to `validate`, and everything went along as expected.

My understanding is to use `validates` with normal validations, and `validate` with custom ones. Is that right? Are there any other pieces I should know about? Is there any way to have the first problem fail loudly and not just validate everything?

Comment: perhaps one is custom validation syntax `validate` and other is generic validation `validates` syntax

Comment: @Viren - I'm just wondering if I missed anything else. I wasn't able to find a clear explanation of the two and I'm hoping SO can provide. I agree, that's the only difference I've found so far.

Comment: I answered it keeping mind the issue of lighthouse :)

Answer (score 92, accepted):

**validates** This method is a shortcut to all default validators and any custom validator classes ending in ‘Validator’. Note that Rails default validators can be overridden inside specific classes by creating custom validator classes in their place such as PresenceValidator.

```
validates :title, :body, :presence => true
```

**validate**, Adds a validation method or block to the class. This is useful when overriding the validate instance method becomes too unwieldy and you’re looking for more descriptive declaration of your validations.

```
validate :must_be_friends

  def must_be_friends
    errors.add(:base, 'Must be friends to leave a comment') unless commenter.friend_of?(commentee)
  end
```

Comment: out of `curiosity` which doc can you attach the link and also did you tested it AFAIK it does not work

Comment: revised my answer :)  this one: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates I've read the examples lower and that's what I understood, but looks like I was wrong. The more descriptive ones http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about the "custom validator classes ending in ‘Validator’" bit, that's really good to know. I'll leave the question open for a bit longer in case other answers come up, but I'll be back later to accept. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: The custom validators are pretty simple to understand, and the regular ones you've seen (eg `validates :title, :presence => true`) merely use the custom Validators that ship with Rails. See: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/presence.rb. You can see how this works in the source code for the `validates` method: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb#L111

Comment: does that above code validate if commenter belongs_to commentee?

Answer (score 12):

I believe the `:validate` declaration is used for **custom** validation where as `:validates` is used for **generic** validation like `presence, uniqueness etc` on a field

The `validate` method looks for a method with the parameter's name, i.e.
 if you do `validate :field` it will look for

```
def field 

end
```

on your `object`. Since Rails defines an `attr_accessor` for every database `field` the `validate :field` would call the `field`'s reader method.

If the validation function returns `true` or if there is an `error` object, i.e. `object.errors` is not empty, then the object is considered `valid?`

Hence the reason in `ligthouse` issue, they complain that `validate`  `silently bypasses` the validation :)

Hope this make sense

Comment: Ah, thanks for that explanation! I hadn't thought of it that way, but it completely makes sense. It also explains why you couldn't have the `:validate` fail "loudly" since it is a perfectly reasonable (one might even say "valid"...) call to make. I hadn't thought of it like that.

Comment: **This is extremely important.** _Seriously_ unexpected results are but a single character away. Thanks for posting not only the "gotcha" but the science behind it. Cheers!

Comment: The rails API is confusing in that respect - the silent failure of validation methods is problematic, especially if they aren't caught by tests.