# Is there any difference between validate and validates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I would like to know if there is any differences between "validate" and "validates". Like this:

```
validates :title, presence: true
```

And

```
 validate :title, presence: true
```

I know is just a 's'... but you never know!

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18140898/whats-the-difference-between-validate-and-validates/18141015#18141015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know:

validates is used for built in validations like `validates :name, length: { minimum: 2 }`
While validate is used for custom validations like:

```
validate :some_validation
def some_validation
    if found_error
         self.errors.add #...
    end
end
```